# Error installing Tweepy for Python (Mac)

Tags: python-2.7, pip, tweepy

I'm working with Python 2.6.6 and have been trying to download tweepy, but whenever I import tweepy in the Python IDLE shell it comes back with a "No module named tweepy" error.

I've downloaded tweepy using

```
sudo pip install tweepy
```

And it goes right into /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages with no problems.

Then I cd from that path into tweepy and

```
python setup.py install
```

but this error message comes up

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'python': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've gone through the path and everything is correct with Python at the end.

However, when I open up a Python IDLE shell and

```
import tweepy
```

the "No module named tweepy" error comes up.

I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is using Python 2.7, as you can tell from the `site-packages` path, while you are apparently trying to install for use with 2.6. Leaving aside the question of why you're using 2.6, the problem is easy enough to fix - install `pip` with Python 2.6.

Download [`get-pip.py`](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py), then (assuming your `python` command points to version 2.6) run:

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Once it's installed, you should be able to run

```
sudo pip2.6 install tweepy
```

and everything should work properly.

Comment: I use python 2.7 It shows following error when `sudo pip install tweepy` is executed: `OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-CSR9pt-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'`

Comment: @AditiNarware first, I'd **strongly** recommend using Python 3. Second, don't use *or modify* the system Python - it's a special version for the internal use of OS X, but can lead to problems with regular developer use. Install Python from MacPorts, Homebrew, or python.org. Then, use virtualenvs to install new packages.